# issue with shadow background size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a shadow size but not work

**Current Output:**

[image: Current Output:]

**What I want to:**

[image]

index.cshtml

```
<h2 id="tstby"><b>WE SERVE SEVERAL INDUSTRIES</b></h2>
```

style.css

```
#tstby {
    background-image: url('../Graphics/blackshadow.png');
    background-size: 50px 50px;        //issue is here background size won't work
}
```

Comment: Can you attach working snippet?

Comment: @Derek.W this is my original code sorry I did not understood what are you trying to say

Comment: `What does "background size wont work mean"`, can you attach the image how the screen looks when you set the background-size?

Comment: @Derek.W problem is here 50px(width) 50px(height) why not work I tested in console also

Comment: So you have set `background-size: 50px 50px;` and you can see the first image on the question description?

Comment: @Derek.W see console log https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLoma.png

Comment: I see. I have attached my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size` CSS attribute is working correctly.

You can see that current output because you have not set the `background-repeat` CSS attribute. By default, the background image is repeated on both `X` & `Y` direction if the size is smaller than the selector size.

So it is needed to set `background-repeat: no-repeat` on your style and you will see size works.

So the style should be

```
#tstby {
    background-image: url('../Graphics/blackshadow.png');
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: when I give the margin-left on shadow then whole content move the left side see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEsTT.png can you help more

Comment: If you want to move the background only, use `background-position` css attribute. See this reference. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: it is possible to give width and height of background position?

Comment: You can give width and height on `background-size` and align that on `background-position`.

Comment: is too much left https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnCnQ.png

Comment: It is needed to see the reference to the end. You can set like this. `background-position: 50px  150px` (first param is x pos and second param is y pos)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `:before` selector and adding the (positioning and) styling of the grey block to that element. There's no need for a `background-image`.

Also the heading element is by default a block-element, therefore `display: inline-block;` is needed.

```css
#tstby:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  left: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}

#tstby {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="tstby"><b>WE SERVE SEVERAL INDUSTRIES</b></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe positioning the `b` element inside your div could work:

```css
/* for demo */
body {
    padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

#tstby {
    background-image: url('../Graphics/blackshadow.png');
    background-size: 50px 50px;

   
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    
    /* for demo */
    background-color: grey;
}

#tstby b {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="tstby"><b>WE SERVE SEVERAL INDUSTRIES</b></h2>
```